# c# split list of tuple into multiple lists

Tags: c#

Assuming I have the following list of tuples:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>>

{"Name", "xx"},{"Age", "25"},{"PostalCode", "12345"},{"Name", "yy"},{"Age", "30"},{"PostalCode", "67890"}
```

I want to split this list into multiple lists. Splitting criteria is `Item1 == "Name"`

Result should be following:

List 1:

> {"Name", "xx"},{"Age", "25"},{"PostalCode", "12345"}

List 2:

> {"Name", "yy"},{"Age", "30"},{"PostalCode", "67890"}

I have a solution where I note down the indexes of "Name" in the original list and create new lists by using the function `GetRange`. But there must be a better and faster way of doing this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a simple class that holds your data?

Comment: These tuples are of different types, `<string, string>` or `<string, int>` how you keep them originally?

Comment: I have edited my question. List contains a tuple of <string, string>.
Am getting data like this from an external interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ to find all the indices of `Name` and select it and the following 3 entries into a new list.

This assumes that the original list is well-formed such that for every `Name` there is guaranteed to be two valid fields following it.

```
var data = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    new Tuple<string, string>("Name", "xx"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("Age", "25"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("PostalCode", "12345"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("ignoreMe", "345"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("Name", "yy"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("Age", "30"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("PostalCode", "67890")
};

var lists = data
    .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
    .Where(x => x.Value.Item1 == "Name")
    .Select(x => data.Skip(x.Index).Take(3))
    .ToList();
```

And also, there are probably more performant solutions than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumrable.Range` to loop trough your list and select your desired tuples:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> data = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    new Tuple<string, string>("Name", "xx"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("Age", "25"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("PostalCode", "12345"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("Name", "yy"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("Age", "30"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("PostalCode", "67890")
};

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Count).Where(i => data[i].Item1 == "Name")
            .Select(i => data.Skip(i).Take(3).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

You can test my code here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/6fJumx